# What is the meaning of the term 'OP' used here?

Tags: discussion

I want to know the meaning of the term 'OP' used here?
What is the exact meaning of 'op'?
Is it an abbreviation of something?

Comment: OP is the acronym for Original Poster.

Comment: OP can also mean 'Original Post'.

Answer (score 4):

OP is an acronym for "Original Poster". In this question, that's you, 박용현!

OP is used in a lot of online communities to refer to the person that originally created the content that people are commenting on.

As suggested by @Lawrence, OP may also refer to the content itself, not its creator.